# Django Api - 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, api

I get this Attribute Error 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

views.py

---

```
def display_mobiles(request,*args,**kwargs):
    items = Mobiles.objects.all()                                   
    context = {
        'items': items,
    }                                                               
    data_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', context)
    return JsonResponse(data_serialized,safe=False)
```

---

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a dictionary to the serializer, just the items themselves.

Note also, you shouldn't use JsonResponse with already serialized data. Just use a standard HttpResponse with the correct content type.

```
def display_mobiles(request,*args,**kwargs):
    items = Mobiles.objects.all()                                   
    data_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', items)
    return HttpResponse(data_serialized, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thank you very much